# Get size of remote file from google drive URL

Tags: php, google-drive-api, drive

Is there a way to get the size of a remote file https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=54fs54dg45f1f112f2 before downloading the file?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a curl request to get `sizeBytes`.

```
<?php
$id = '0ByzJffaEk18uN2ZLeGlIRGVOaDJmWS1WU1RUN3d***';

$ch = curl_init('https://drive.google.com/uc?id='.$id.'&export=download');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, []);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));                                                                                                                                                                          
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$object = json_decode(str_replace(')]}\'', '', $result));

print_r($object);
```

**Result:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [disposition] => SCAN_CLEAN
    [downloadUrl] => https://doc-08-8o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/...
    [fileName] => filename.sh
    [scanResult] => OK
    [sizeBytes] => 4936
)
```